# sql - insert query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have this table and I want to insert values, but it's not working:

```
MariaDB [worldmap]> show columns from worldmap_table;
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| servername          | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| trigger_description | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| long                | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lat                 | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sev1                | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sev2                | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sev3                | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sev4                | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sev5                | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| severity            | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```sql
insert into  worldmap_table (servername ,trigger_description, long, lat, sev1, sev2, sev3, sev4, sev5, severity)
    values ("titi", "tata", 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 9)
```

But I get this message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'long, lat, sev1, sev2, sev3, sev4, sev5, severity)
>   values ("titi", "tata", 3, 2' at line 1

Comment: `long` is a reserved word: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-L. Enclose it in backticks

Answer (score 3):

Your query needs backticks, and perhaps also the autoincrement field, with value NULL to trigger a new increment:

```
insert into  worldmap_table (servername ,trigger_description, long, lat, sev1, sev2, sev3, sev4, sev5, severity)
values ("titi", "tata", 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 9)
```

should be

```
insert into  worldmap_table (`ID`, `servername` ,`trigger_description`, `long`, `lat`, `sev1`, `sev2`, `sev3`, `sev4`, `sev5`, `severity`)
values (NULL, "titi", "tata", 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 9);
```

Comment: Back-ticks are only required for reserved keywords. (But can be used for all identifiers.)

Comment: @jarlh correct, and I would also suggest never using reserved keywords as column names, since they are... reserved.